# Drupal Quick Tabs - Add a link to external site or node in tab list

Tags: drupal, tabs, drupal-7

I have a few tabs, but would like to make another that appears to be a tab link but when clicked, would just link to an external page or node. No tab view would load for it, simply a redirect.

Is this possible?

Comment: have you found a way to do this without using jQuery / Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use jQuery, something like this:

```
(function($) {
  $("#YOUR-QUICKTAB_ID").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
})(jQuery);
```